# How to find earlier element by partial id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I trying to find the parent div of a clicked item but can only get it working by manually setting the div id. There are many similar divs with incrementing id's

```
<div id="grid0"...
<div id="grid1"...
<div id="grid2"...
etc
```

My javscript is as follows but this only finds the first grid

```
    function popUp1HtmlContent(e) {
        var dataItem = $("div[id^=grid]").data("kGrid").dataItem(e.target.closest("tr"));
        var content = dataItem.PopUp1Html;
        return content;
    }
```

How do I find the parent div in this function?

Eg setting this manually works for each grid

```
var dataItem = $("div[id=grid0]").data("kGrid").dataItem(e.target.closest("tr"));
var dataItem = $("div[id=grid1]").data("kGrid").dataItem(e.target.closest("tr"));
```

etc

Is there a way to search back through the parents to find the first matching div with id starting "grid{0}"?

The event fires from an image within a td element. Also it's not always the direct parent but can have varying number of elements between clicked element and div I'm trying to locate.

Comment: The proper way to do this is with a class, not an ID. That's what classes are for; each div should have a `grid` class and a `grid#` id. That gives you a more efficient lookup. Anyway, you can use jQuery's `closest()` method to search up the DOM hierarchy.

Comment: Have you tried .parents()? $('img.class').parents([id^=grid]).data("kGrid")...

Comment: @vyx.ca `parents()` can return more than one result. For the OP's case of finding the first matching div, `closest()` is correct.

Comment: @sbking true. Good point.

Comment: @sbking Ah okay, I didn't realise I could use the closest() multiple times, this works `var dataItem = $(e.target.closest("div[id^=grid]")).data("kGrid").dataItem(e.target.closest("tr"));`  But note your point about using class instead of id. If you add an answer I'll accept.